# How can I make Time Machine back up my virtual machines?

Tags: virtualbox, backup, time-machine

It seems Time Machine only checks the size of a file and not the date modified to back up. I have a Windows Virtual box and it does not back it up even though the date modified has changed since the last backup (because the virtual box file (`.vdi`) has not changed size).

Any ideas? Is there a setting to force Time Machine to check the date as well?

Comment: As an aside: if you use a MacBook and have [local snapshots enabled](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14329), then the huge VM files might eat up a lot of space, hence limiting the number of snapshots that are kept locally.

Comment: As for limiting the backup size: you might want to read [Time machine friendly virtual machine (VirtualBox) image files?](http://superuser.com/questions/364585/time-machine-friendly-virtual-machine-virtualbox-image-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was it ever backed up at all? As far as I know, a changed timestamp should include it.

However, your virtual machine image might also have been excluded using the extended attribute `com.apple.metadata:com_apple_backup_excludeItem` on the file. Use the `xattr` command in Terminal to see extended attributes.

See [Does Apple's Time Machine app really copy everthing](https://superuser.com/questions/71824/does-apples-time-machine-app-really-copy-everthing) for more details.

Comment: Well it was always backing up before I upgraded to Maverick from Mountain Lion. I am wondering if that had an effect and what else is not being backed up. xattr "Windows 7.vdi"  shows nothing.

   
110680576 -rw-------  1 myself  staff  56668454912 Jul 29 06:31 Windows 7.vdi

Comment: Eh, @user603749, now that you accepted this: did this work for you? Your comment says that `xattr` didn't show anything? (Also, your `ls` output doesn't show an `@`, to indicate the file has extended attributes.) Was it excluded somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apple's **tmutil** to control which files/directories are backed up by using this command to allow them to be backed up (if they're excluded):

```
sudo tmutil removeexclusion your_file_or_dir
```

One can also exclude files/dir using this command:

```
sudo tmutil addexclusion your_file_or_dir
```